# Did something that made right margin goofy

Tags: margins

I'm editing a `.tex` file, adding a color box around changes I make.

Had this:

```
\vpara{Problem:} Given $k$ social networks $\textbf{G} = \{G_1, G_2, ..., G_k\}$, 
we want to output a set of partial one-to-one mappings $\textbf{M} = \{\textbf{M}_{i,j}\}$ 
where $\forall i, j = 1,2,...,k; i > j$. Each $m = (v_i, v_j) \in \textbf{M}_{i,j}$ denotes the 
two accounts $v_i$ and $v_j$ belonging to the same person, and by partial, we mean that one person 
may have an account on $G_i$ but do not have account on $G_j$.
```

Changed to this:

```
\vpara{Problem:} Given $k$ social networks $\textbf{G} = \{G_1, G_2, ..., G_k\}$, we want to 
output a set of partial one-to-one mappings $\textbf{M} = \{\textbf{M}_{i,j}\}$\colorbox{yellow}{,} 
where $\forall i, j = 1,2,...,k; i > j$. Each $m = (v_i, v_j) \in \textbf{M}_{i,j}$ 
denotes the two accounts $v_i$ and $v_j$ belonging to the same person\colorbox{yellow}{. 
We designate as \textit{partial} a mapping for which a person may have an account on $G_i$ 
but not on $G_j$.}
```

Now the line beginning "We designate..." does not break at the right margin in the PDF; just goes right across the page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In particular, what does \vpara do?  I've never heard of that.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful guidance, Christian and Werner!

Answer (score 2):

I still don't know what `\vpara` does, but I suspect that your problem is with `\colorbox`.  It seems that you just want to highlight text.  For that, the soul package is preferable to using `\colorbox`. Presumably this does what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}
Problem: Given $k$ social networks $\textbf{G} = \{G_1, G_2, ..., G_k\}$, we want to 
output a set of partial one-to-one mappings $\textbf{M} = \{\textbf{M}_{i,j}\}$\colorbox{yellow}{,} 
where $\forall i, j = 1,2,...,k; i > j$. Each $m = (v_i, v_j) \in \textbf{M}_{i,j}$ 
denotes the two accounts $v_i$ and $v_j$ belonging to the same person\hl{. 
We designate as \textit{partial} a mapping for which a person may have an account on $G_i$ 
but not on $G_j$.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (Tobi, I am an editor, and this is my first foray into the world of TeX; I don't know what \vpara does either.) Thank you for the soul recommendation, Jpi!